# How to read file contents in an array using shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script which reads a file in to an array. It works perfectly with RHEL, but when i run the same script on Ubuntu i am getting an error. Here is the script.

```
file=/root/monitor.txt
while IFS=',' read -ra line ; do
        echo -e "export MASTER_IP=${line[2]}" >> ~/.bashrc
        source ~/.bashrc
done < $file
```

The above script works perfectly in RHEL. The error i am getting when i run it on Ubuntu is

```
read: Illegal option -a
```

Comment: The `-a` option is just for bash. Check this page [Unix - Using Shell Arrays](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-using-arrays.htm) for reference.

Comment: For pure POSIX sh, arrays don't exist -- they're a ksh feature adopted by bash, zsh, etc. Fortunately, you don't need them.

Answer (score 5):

`read -a` is a bash feature, but on Ubuntu `/bin/sh` points to `dash`, which doesn't support the `-a` option. There are a few ways you could solve this problem:

- On Ubuntu, just run the script under bash, by changing the first line to `#!/bin/bash` (as suggested by Charles Duffy)
- Instead of `read -a`, just give a list of variables, such as `read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5` and then refer to the fields as `$f1`, `$f2` etc. In this case, if you have more than 5 fields, you need to add more variables, otherwise `$f5` will contain the rest of the line.
- Use `awk` instead of `read`. Awk is a good fit for this kind of field-processing task: you could replace the while loop with something like `awk -F, '{print "export MASTER_IP=" $3}' $file >> ~/.bashrc`, and then source `~/.bashrc` at the end.

Comment: I'd at least directly mention changing the shebang as an option.

Comment: I didn't think of that, that's a much nicer solution. I've edited it in. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
while IFS=, read -r _ _ ip _; do
  printf 'export MASTER_IP=%s\n' "$ip"
done <"$file" >>"$HOME/.bashrc"
```

This is better in a few respects:

- Doesn't require any bashisms; will work with `/bin/sh` on Ubuntu.
- Opens the output file only once for the whole loop, instead of inefficiently reopening it every time a new line is to be written.

However, you can do better -- improving your script's security -- if you change its shebang to be `#!/bin/bash` (or `/usr/bin/env bash`, or otherwise as appropriate for your platform):

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=, read -r _ _ ip _; do
  printf 'export MASTER_IP=%q\n' "$ip"
done <"$file" >>"$HOME/.bashrc"
```

Because this uses `%q` instead of `%s`, it also escapes the addresses, so they can't contain malicious content like `$(rm -rf $HOME)` -- something you probably don't want injected into your `~/.bashrc`.